# Experience Editor error when adding element to placeholder in a JSS component that doesn't by default render its placeholder

Tags: experience-editor, jss

I'm using sitecore JSS, I have a component with a placeholder and I am trying to add a child component into that placeholder. I'm getting an unhelpful popup error saying `An error occurred` and then in the console I get the slightly more descriptive, but also largely unhelpful error `Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server`.

I've been able to narrow down the problem to what the component renders as a default on SSR:

```
import React from "react";
import { withPlaceholder, isExperienceEditorActive } from "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react";
import { DeviceWidth } from "../Utils/device";
import { CardList, MobileCardList, CardListSkeleton } from "componentlib";


const JSSCardCarousel = ({ fields, cardCarouselPlaceholder }) => {
  if (isExperienceEditorActive()) {
    return <div>{cardCarouselPlaceholder}</div>;
  }
  return width === DeviceWidth.Unknown ? (
    // Note the Skeleton, default state doesn't render the placeholder on purpose
    <CardListSkeleton />
  ) : (
    <CardList>{cardCarouselPlaceholder}</CardList>
    <MobileCardList>{cardCarouselPlaceholder</CardList>
  );
};

export default withPlaceholder({
  placeholder: "card-carousel-placeholder",
  prop: "cardCarouselPlaceholder"
})(JSSCardCarousel);
```

I have a trimmed down section component that holds cards. If i know it's EE, i return the cards placeholder in a div. Otherwise if I don't know the device width (i.e., I'm SSR) , I render a skeleton state and then when I get to the client, we render a card list and mobile card list (they use breakpoints to determine which to show. The problem is with the `CardListSkeleton`. In EE, that is the default case for this component. This works fine in normal rendering of the page, but in EE, a component that does not render it's placeholder as it's default case throws the error I mentioned earlier: `Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server`.

This seems like a legitimate bug in the experience editor.

We have this issue with multiple components (e.g., a modal component that only renders the placeholder contents into the dom when the modal opens). If there was a way to ensure `isExperienceEditorActive()` on SSR, I think this would be a lot better. My workaround right now is to always render the placeholder in a `<span hidden>{myplaceholder}</span>` by default alongside the *actual default*. Pretty irritating that I have to encode my placeholder contents twice on the page in order to appease one small facet of the EE.

Any other help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior seems unexpected and feels like a legitimate bug in how the Experience Editor (EE) is handling jss renderings (i.e., the fact that if a rendering doesn't by default render the placeholder server-side, it doesn't blow up when trying to add to that rendering's placeholder in EE).

Here's the best workaround to this problem that I've now gone with:

Use [`sitecoreContext && sitecoreContext.pageEditing`](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/react/src/components/Styleguide-Layout-Tabs/index.js#L32) via the [`withSitecoreContext` HOC](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/client-frameworks/react/sample-app#sitecore-context-access) instead of `isExperienceEditorActive` to ensure that, in the EE, the component is always rendered ***client and server side*** with its placeholder. Apparently `isExperienceEditorActive` works exclusively on client side and will never return true if rendering on the server, even if in the experience editor. So my updated component would look something like:

```
import React from "react";
import { withPlaceholder, withSitecoreContext } from "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react";
import { DeviceWidth } from "../Utils/device";
import { CardList, MobileCardList, CardListSkeleton } from "componentlib";
import compose from "ramda/src/compose"; // Or use from redux, recompose, lodash, roll your own, etc...

const JSSCardCarousel = ({ fields, cardCarouselPlaceholder, sitecoreContext }) => {
  const isEditing = sitecoreContext && sitecoreContext.pageEditing;

  if (isEditing) {
    return <div>{cardCarouselPlaceholder}</div>;
  }
  return width === DeviceWidth.Unknown ? (
    // Note the Skeleton, default state doesn't render the placeholder on purpose
    <CardListSkeleton />
  ) : (
    <CardList>{cardCarouselPlaceholder}</CardList>
    <MobileCardList>{cardCarouselPlaceholder</CardList>
  );
};

const withComposedHOCs = compose(
  withSitecoreContext(),
  withPlaceholder({
    placeholder: "card-carousel-placeholder",
    prop: "cardCarouselPlaceholder"
  })
);

export default withComposedHOCs(JSSCardCarousel);
```

Hopefully Sitecore can address this bug, but in the meantime I hope this workaround helps other folks.